# share NSPersistentCloudKitContainer between app and extension

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I have an embedded framework that defines my core data container on CloudKit with:

`let container =  NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: containerName, managedObjectModel: objectModel)`

This embedded framework is used by the app to insert/read data in this coredata container.

I want to add an (intent) app extension that may act directly on this same coredata container.

How can I access this CloudKit container from the extension? Is there a way to do that? And also how to share the same object model file (.xcdatamodeld) between app and extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Core Data from both container app and extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684256/accessing-core-data-from-both-container-app-and-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [App Group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412643-containerurl), and I can provide you this [example](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/core-data-app-extension-data-sharing/) for starting point.

Also if you are interested in how to pass data from Siri intent to your app, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174039/how-to-manage-that-siri-intent-launches-my-app-and-transfers-data-to-the-app/66175918#66175918)

Comment: I used the example you mentionned but it does not work simply because this example does not talk about CloudKit. It does not answer the actual question